# Microsoft Scrum Process Template 2.1 vs 2.2

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-process-template

Visual Studio TFS Update 2 updated the Scrum Process Template from 2.1 to 2.2.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find any information on the exact changes.

What changed between the versions? And, more importantly, how can I determine what changes are important for my project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for a similar list of changes and, much like you, haven't had much luck. Here is the closest I've come to a list of new features:

"From Scrum 2.0 to Scrum 2.2
 - Add the Tags column by default on the product backlog
 - Add missing transitions to the Bug and PBI"

Which I found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/04/04/upgrade-your-2012-process-template-from-rtm-to-update-2.aspx.